# Running test suite with dependencies in testng with selenium

Tags: java, xml, maven, selenium, testng

### Hi I have multiple class which has different wep application url to perform testing. When I define all the class under single test suite, testng does not run the test as per define in testng.xml file. for example

```
<suite name="Auto Test" preserve-order="true" parallel="instances"
thread-count="10">

<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.automation.core.listeners.CustomReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter" />
    <listener class-name="org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter" />
</listeners>

<test name="test1" preserve-order="true">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="functest" />
            <exclude name="inprogress" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test1" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="test2" preserve-order="true">
    <groups>
        <run>
            <include name="functest" />
            <exclude name="inprogress" />
        </run>
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.test2" />
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Now when i run the maven pom file, system first run the test2 instead of test1. Can we define dependencies on tests'. I am new to this and could not find my way to solve this? I am using maven with testng, selenium and java. I would appreciate you help

Thanks,

Comment: What plugin version do u have in eclipse and what is the testng jar version in your dependencies?

Comment: Thanks, for your response- here is details                         eclipse helios = Build id: 20110218-0911
testng jar = 6.8 - in dependencies
m2e = 1.4.1
testng in eclipse =6.8.6

Comment: and ur surefire plugin version in pom?

Comment: it is maven-surefire-plugin 2.6

Comment: preserve-order is true by default.  I am not seeing the behavior when I tried it.  Can you try changing your surefire plugin version to latest -2.18 I suppose

Comment: Do we need to keep all the test class under one package? like, com.test1 and com.test2. As all my test class are under different package like com.script.test1.test, com.script.test2.test2. Also, I have tried using 2.18 but no luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66244/discussion-between-karim-narsindani-and-niharika-neo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to put a closure to the question, parallel was changed to false in the suite tag, surefire plugin was updated.  There was a code issue in the test that was causing the mentioned issue.